# Pulling back multiple queries in a single call to fill a Dataset from Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, data-access

I have an application that supports both SQL Server and Oracle as the back end database.

On SQL Server I can add two queries into a single ODBCommand string and when it runs it Fills a Dataset, creating two DataTables in the Dataset, one for each of the queries.

```
string command = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 SELECT * FROM TABLE2"    

var dbConnection = GetOdbcConnection();

var dataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(completeSqlString, dbConnection);
dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
```

However, this won't work against the Oracle back end. I get an error

> ORA-00911: invalid character error.

But both queries work in SQL Developer.

I have added the ; to show the end of one query, I have tried wrapping both the queries in a BEGIN...END  But it's not working.  Everything I find on line is about retrieving one datapoint from each of the queries and selecting that into a variable.

Is this possible?  What do I need to do to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why using ODBC instead of the native provider? Did you try if your queries work with the native provider? (also missing a semicolon to separate the two queries)

Comment: Hi, @Steve.  The ODBC thing is a restriction set elsewhere in the application.  The example above was as I write it for SQL but I do have the semicolons in the Oracle version of the Query.  One at the end of each query.

Comment: It could be a limitation in the Oracle ODBC driver. However I can't find anything related to this problem searching for _oracle batch statements_ or _oracle multiple queries_

Comment: The only thing I found seems to be REF CURSORS???  But I've not heard of them before.  I might have a bit of reading to do over the weekend...